# Using dll at runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, mono

I want to use my dll at runtime by code.(Not putting the dll at Plugin asset)
So I write this code below:

Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\HaoranZhu\workspace\UnityProjects\ViveDRMSDKTest\Assets\Plugins\x86_64\vita_api.dll");

But it shows the error here in Unity console:

BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'D:\HaoranZhu\workspace\UnityProjects\ViveDRMSDKTest\Assets\Plugins\x86_64\vita_api.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom (System.String assemblyFile) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:520)
loadExternalDll.Start () (at Assets/TestScripts/loadExternalDll.cs:16)

what's the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure vita_api.dll doesn't have any dependiencies to other assemblies? Have you tried using the 32 bit instead?

Comment: did you try just loading it in plugins first to make sure it works at all?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because (according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx):

**----BadImageFormatException----** 
*assemblyFile* is not a valid assembly; for example, a 32-bit assembly in a 64-bit process. See the exception topic for more information.
**-or-**
Version 2.0 or later of the common language runtime is currently loaded and *assemblyFile* was compiled with a later version.

**---**

This means that either a you are using a 32-bit assembly when the process is 64 bit, (just get a 64-bit version).

Or if you downloaded a library for a later version of the common language runtime.

Comment: yeah I've seen it on Microsoft's website. A really weird question is, when I put the dll in Assets/Plugins and in C# script using 'using namespace',it works just fine. But if I use it by the scripts"Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFrom(XXX)" , it just have an error. I don't know why.

Comment: well they are basically the only ways you can have this error from. Does the method work for any other DLL files?